# Error in plugin solidity-coverage: HardhatPluginError: Warning: X contracts exceed the size limit for mainnet deployment

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

When I run the solidity-coverage plugin in hardhat, I have this error message :

*Error in plugin solidity-coverage: HardhatPluginError: Warning: 3 contracts exceed the size limit for mainnet deployment.*

However, when I compile the contracts they do not exceed the size limit. This happens only when I run the plugin. The test suite runs perfectly with no error neither.

I added `allowUnlimitedContractSize: true` in the hardhat network config but still got the error. There is probably some more configuration needed.

I am using `solidity-coverage : 0.8.2`

Is there a way to ignore this error and run the coverage correctly ?

Comment: Can you share the contract bytecode?

Answer (score 0):

It worked using `solidity-coverage v0.7.20` and adding in hardhat.config.js :

```
contractSizer: {
   runOnCompile: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are ignoring the contract size check with the plugin but you should have added optimizer to optimize the contract size

```
 settings: {
  optimizer: {
    enabled: true,
    runs: 5000,
 }}
```

Comment: Be aware that enabling optimizer only reduces the contract size depending on the number of runs. The higher the number of runs the size increases and the gas used when calling methods is reduced. The lower the number the lower the size but the gas used when calling methods increases